# Unable to fetch data from mongodb using expressjs

Tags: mongodb, express

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/recart";

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, async (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("recart");
        var result = await dbo.collection("users").find()
        res.json(result.data)
  });
})

app.listen(3001, ()=> {
    console.log('App is running on port 3001');
})
```

Here I am trying to fetch data from mongodb using expressjs,
but in my browser nothing is coming.

No data is coming. But in my database there are documents.

Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/recart";
```

Do you really need to provide collection's name here?

You can try:

```
const mongoUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/'
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
      const client = await MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, {
        useNewUrlParser: true
      })
      const db = client.db("database_name")
      const data = await db.collection("collection_name").find().toArray()
    res.json(data)
 }),
```